# Javascript: How to get the all properties of `prototype` or `__proto__` of an Object or Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype

As we know `Object.keys` will return the own properties of an Object or Array, But I need all the  properties of `Array or Object`. If you see below image, all the properties of  `[].__proto__ and {}.__proto__` are not `enumerable`.

What is the best way to get the all `properties` including `own` and `__proto__`?

[image]

**What is the best way to get the all `properties` including `own` and `__proto__`?**

I tried the following approach, Not sure whether best approach or not.

Example:

```js
const getAllProperties = ref => {
   const own_properites = Object.keys(ref)
   const proto_properties = Object.keys(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(ref.__proto__))
   return [...own_properites, ...proto_properties]
}

const object = {
   name: 'A'
};

console.log({ objectProps: getAllProperties(object) })

const array = [1,2,3];

console.log({ arrayProps: getAllProperties(array) });
```

Comment: I bet these answers better than the reference link? what do you say @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten it somewhat by using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead of going through the descriptors first. Also, your current method is getting the `Object.keys` of the instance, but `Object.keys` skips non-enumerable properties:

```js
const obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', { value: 'value' });
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

So, use `getOwnPropertyNames` both for the instance and for the prototype.

You could also consider using `Object.getPrototypeOf`, unlike the deprecated `__proto__`.

```js
const getAllProperties = ref => [
  ...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ref),
  ...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(ref)),
];

const object = {
   name: 'A'
};

console.log({ objectProps: getAllProperties(object) })

const array = [1,2,3];

console.log({ arrayProps: getAllProperties(array) });
```